# Rails code only runs Once in Each Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iterator, dataset, each

I have a loop that runs through each piece of artwork in a database. Inside the loop, there is embedded rails url helper code. The problem is that only runs once, on the first iteration through the loop. It should be printing on each piece of artwork, not just the first one iterated through:

```
<% @artwork_q.each_with_index do |art, index| %>
    <%= image_tag art.photo.url(:listing) %>
    <div class="update-photo"><%= link_to "Update", edit_artwork_path(art.id) %></div>
    <div class="delete-photo"><%= link_to "Delete", artwork_path(art.id), 'data-method' => :delete, 'data-confirm' => "Are you sure?" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What exactly does it "print"? If you replace the code by `@artwork_q.inspect` what does it show?

Comment: Could you add the definition of `@artwork_q` in the controller.